# Left space on first letter CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I am using the Google font 'Lato' and I am having problems with having title and text align properly to the left... The font (when large) appears to have a kern space on the first letter and wont align left without space!?

[image: Image of kerning problem on first letter of sentance]

So here also a fiddle:

```
<h1>Hello</h1> <p>Hello, this is sentance</p>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/unit60/w25j9L7o/)

Also, adding a negative value on the margin-left (magin-left:-10px) just seems like a terrible workaround... and this would not work overall for different font-sizes, unless individually adjusted as needed... surly there must be a better solution?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Adding a negative value on the margin-left just seems like a terrible workaround... and this would not work overall for different font-sizes, unless individually adjusted as needed... surly there must be a better solution?

Comment: It's almost fine from `h2` onwards. But it's fine when you don't change the font size of the `h1`. Maybe the font itself isn't designed to be viewed at large sizes.

Comment: @Morgan add the margin:0px and padding:0px in your body css style

Comment: @rJ7 Problem is not in margins on paddings you can test it in Inspect element (F12) Font has spaces each letter. It cannot be changed br css only by editing font itself

Comment: @Morgan It is not possible in another way. If you select / highlight (make it blue) you can see the margin on the left side of the h1 is larger then the p. this is because the font-size is bigger, and when the fontsize gets bigger, the margin gets bigger. You can not do anything about that

Comment: I have ideal solution for you @Morgan use Gill Sans font instead it is very similar to Lato.

Comment: @Lafontein - I was totally thinking Gill Sans!! (But if you check out the licensing cost for Gill Sans, I'd hardly call it ideal.)

Comment: @Morgan Yes 35$. I will find now free font with same visual.

Comment: LOL... I can't believe that this oversight has been allowed to filter through unnoticed by google... Love GillSans, but can't let bad technology hold me back or tie me to convention :)

Comment: @Morgan I have added font link in my comment you can download it.

Comment: @Morgan I checked it without font lato it throws same problem check with my solution it will work

Answer (score 23):

Okay, everyone who says it's due to automatic padding or margins due to the line being a header is wrong. See this fiddle as evidence:

http://jsfiddle.net/w25j9L7o/26/

The leading space is not being rendered by the browser or the CSS or anything else at the DOM/Browser level. It is the font. The `H` glyph has some built-in padding around it, and the larger the font size, the more noticeable that padding will be.

Even if you use negative margins to compensate:

1. The character itself is shifting over, which includes the empty space, so that empty space will be sliding over as well, affecting layout. The visible character isn't sliding into the empty space, the entire character (visible and invisible) is shifting to the left if you use CSS to fix it.
2. You would need to adjust that offset based on the font-size or figure out the underlying percentage so that the offset grows with any font-size set.

Or you can just use a different font that doesn't have this characteristic.

Comment: you are correct... I have tried a couple of other Google hosted fonts and find the same problem... I wasn't sure I was just too stupid or something, but alas 'it is in the font', I just didn't want to believe that this could have been an oversight by the designer or Google... very disappointing...

Comment: This is awful, Raleway generates the same problem, and it is my favorite font.

Comment: InDesign provides left-side bearing adjustment for the first letter. This doesn't exist in CSS (yet). Using a negative margin of % or pixels is bad because it won't scale properly when moving to different media or scale. Instead use "rem" units which are relative-em units to the current font. Still not a pretty hack since each letter has its own left-side bearing.

Comment: I ended up looking for an answer to this because I was using Raleway too. Such a pretty font but their spacing on some letter is killing me.

Answer (score 6):

**PX** units are not such a good choice in this case. I recommend using **EM** unit if you working with font attributes like line-height etc. Because it's automatically calculated for each of font-size. It should look like this:

```
#yourDiv::first-letter {
   margin-left: -0.12em;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution because if I decide to adjust the font size later I can set this and forget it.

Answer (score 4):

Try using first letter

```
h1:first-letter {
    margin-left: -10px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w25j9L7o/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can get kern.js from [kernjs.com](http://www.kernjs.com/) and edit your front kerning, like they said on their website "click and drag to adjust your kerning, line-height, letter placement, When you're done, copy the generated CSS and use it in your own stylesheet"

Answer (score 1):

This problem was driving me crazy so here is an elegant solution that uses ::first-letter selector. For example I was able to fix my spacing issue by adding:

```
#yourDiv::first-letter {margin-left:-5px;}
```

Hope this works for others that were in my situation. Here is a link for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp

Answer (score 0):

The white space is there because it is a header. 
You can align it to the left by doing:

```
margin-left: -10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most Web browsers have different default settings for the base margins and padding. This means that if you don't set a margin and padding on your body and html tags, you could get inconsistent results on the page depending upon which browser you're using to view the page.

The best way to solve this is to set all the margins and paddings on the html and body tags to 0:

Add this CSS:

```
html,body {
    font-family:Lato;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

p{margin-left: 11px;}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w25j9L7o/21/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Gill Sans font. It is very similar to Lato. Problem is in Lato font itself not in Css.

[Here is your link for GillSans](http://www71.zippyshare.com/v/ifPb7NYM/file.html)

Comment: @Lafontain, Thanks for the link :) I will be in touch with Google regarding their design oversight!!!

Comment: This is a virus!