# Align element left exactly

Tags: html, css

I want to align heading and paragraph element exactly left. Is there any standard method to do this or I just need to play with padding-left.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700');
*{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
}
h1{
  font-size:100px;
}
p{
  font-size:21px;
}
body{
  padding:100px;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello, I am</p>
<h1>K. Boozer</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur distinctio dolorum nihil voluptatum repudiandae suscipit, excepturi modi quia ratione aliquid ullam esse, qui, culpa officiis natus dicta adipisci provident facilis.</p>
```

Comment: What is the issue? its already left alligned.

Comment: I think you will need to apply some `padding-left` on `p`.

Comment: Yes, but its not exactly aligned. Look carefully.

Comment: Use a CSS reset to equalize things, then use a padding on the container for gutters rather than targeting the individual items. A lot easier/robuster. Also: H1 is not intended the way you use it. Look into your code semantics.

Comment: Thats part of the font. I don't think you can make them align properly without doing some 'hacking'.

Comment: It is basically because of ```font-size``` that you are setting to ```h1```. If this is fixed then you can set ```margin-left``` and you space issue will be fixed.

Comment: The font has some kerning, I think. You can 'hack around it', but you will run into trouble at some point; there really is no way to predict the user's resolution and zoom factor. Besides, it's normal. Look closely; your p font does the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28809771/left-space-on-first-letter-css

Comment: I'd strongly advise to not even bother doing this. It is how fonts in different sizes actually work and you'd have to do specific CSS changes depending on the first character of each element. **DON'T**. EVER.

Answer (score 3):

Use some negative `margin-left` on the h1. The space there occurs because the font size is so large and every font has its own different letter sizes.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700');
*{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
}
h1{
  font-size:100px;
  margin-left: -6px;
}
p{
  font-size:21px;
}
body{
  padding:100px;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello, I am</p>
<h1>K. Boozer</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur distinctio dolorum nihil voluptatum repudiandae suscipit, excepturi modi quia ratione aliquid ullam esse, qui, culpa officiis natus dicta adipisci provident facilis.</p>
```

## About negative margins:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

> **They are extremely valid CSS**
>
> I’m not kidding on this one. W3C even says that, “Negative values for margin properties are allowed…” ‘Nuff said. Check out the [article](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties) for more details.
>
> **Negative margins are not a hack**
>
> This is especially true. It’s because of not understanding negative margins properly that it got its hackish image. It only becomes a hack if you use it to fix an error you made elsewhere.

Comment: OK, Is it the standard way to do it??

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Comment: @KrishnaRana yes, it is

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with your font as it looks as if it is starting the letters slightly off to the right.

You can combat this with using text-indent - if you use something like `-0.1em` then it should get rid of the left padding of the letter no matter it's size:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700');
 * {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
}
p {
  font-size: 21px;
}
body {
  padding: 100px;
}
* { text-indent: -0.08em; }
```

```html
<p>Hello, I am</p>
<h1>K. Boozer</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur distinctio dolorum nihil voluptatum repudiandae suscipit, excepturi modi quia ratione aliquid ullam esse, qui, culpa officiis natus dicta adipisci provident facilis.</p>
```

The only problem with this approach is that if the text goes over 2 or more lines, the subsequent lines won't have the indent

Answer (score -1):

You can use `position: absolute;` in your css file to make the element appear exactly where you want it to. Then define `left: 0px;` or what ever you want that to be. Hope that helps.

see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead with padding top on body css

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700');
*{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
}
h1{
  font-size:100px;
}
p{
  font-size:21px;
}
body{
  padding-top:100px;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello, I am</p>
<h1>K. Boozer</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur distinctio dolorum nihil voluptatum repudiandae suscipit, excepturi modi quia ratione aliquid ullam esse, qui, culpa officiis natus dicta adipisci provident facilis.</p>
```

Comment: This answer is not related to the question

Comment: did you actually understand what is the question?

Comment: Yes, for exect left he need to do body css property padding-top=100px;