# Space within font Using typography

Tags: css, typography

I am using responsive typography.So, On large screen the type is very large. I am positioning the type using.

`position: fixed;
 top: 40px;`

The problem is the typeface has some space within (shown in image) and this space scales with the type. How can I always align the type to 20px from top (and in line with other, no scaling elements)

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the vertical spacing between the lines?

Comment: no - can you see the left and top margin around the type? I guess it is not normally an issue, but my type is huge so it is really noticeable.

Comment: Do you mean the additional space before the letters that is not present in the left upstroke of the `W` & `Y` ?

Comment: the space above the top line - there is a good 6px of space so it looks really off

Comment: Can you provide a working exemple with the related CSS showed?

Comment: Same issue [as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28809771/left-space-on-first-letter-css) I think, your probably not going to have much luck as the space is integral to the font.

Comment: You could fiddle around with `line-height` (bad) and negative `margin` (ugly). However, I think you should show us a working example, maybe there is a *good* solution after all.