# Vuetify title and subtitle not aligned left

Tags: vuetify.js, letter-spacing

I have this vuetify code:

```
    <div class="mb-6">
      <h1 class="text-h4">
        {{title}}
      </h1>
      <p class="subtitle-1 font-weight-thin" v-if="subtitle">{{subtitle}}</p>
    </div>
```

Which produces a `title` and `subtitle` that are not aligned vertically, as visible there:

[image]

The left-space between the title M is wider that the subtitle one.

Any idea why? I reckon this is the first time I have such an issue, hence I believe this is a Vuetify typography issue.

I tried playing with the `letter-spacing` CSS property without success: it changes the space *between the letters* but not in front.
I also tried playing with `margin-block-start` CSS property, but it doesn't change anything.

Thanks for the help

Comment: looks like some CSS applied on your h1 tag and it's causing left space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a vuetify or letter-spacing issue. This comes from **font** you are using. Vuetify uses Google’s **Roboto** font by default.

[There's a playground](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?preview.text=Monitor&preview.text_type=custom) at Google fonts with Roboto font. You may notice that the problem you mentioned is present here as well. By example, there's some space in Regular 400 @64px:
[image: Roboto-regular-400]

Let's test your code using a different font. By example, I'll use CSS `font-family: serif !important;` that fallbacks to Times New Roman at Windows platforms:

[image: Times]

Looks fine, no spacings.

So one solution to fix your problem is to change the font. I believe that there are fonts that are more suitable for websites than Times and that do not have such a problem.

According to [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#example-variable-file), you can change a font for the whole project with one line in `src/sass/variables.scss` file. Keep in mind that this cause project to build **much longer**:

```scss
$body-font-family: 'Work Sans', serif;
```

Possibly you don't want to change a font. So you can change the whole string's position this way:

```css
.text-h4::first-letter {
   margin-left: -0.04em;
}
```

In this case, the unselected lines will align a little, but there will be problems with selection:
[image: selection-problems]

Maybe [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28809771/left-space-on-first-letter-css) will also help you. And there's [a playground at CodePen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/eYeayZV) where you can test some solutions.

Comment: Wow thanks for such great complete answer! This is a super weird behavior for this typo, it feels like the cleanest solution is to move away from it at least for titles. I'll consider it.